# Apply two regex rules in match()

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var url = document.referrer;
var a=document.createElement('a');
a.href=url;
var path = a.pathname;
```

Let's say path is this:

```
/cat-dog-fish/
```

I want to remove leading and trailing slashes, if they exist, else do nothing.

I can do this (removes trailing slash):

```
a.pathname.replace(/\/$/,'')
```

Or this (removes leading slash)

```
a.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
```

But how do I remove both at once, in a oner, if they exist?

Comment: Use the OR `|` operator: `/^\/|\/$/g`

Comment: tried a.pathname.replace(/^\/|\/$/,'') but it removes the leading slash only?

Comment: Make the regex replace all matches (and not just the first match), using the global `g` modifier

Comment: Many thanks, I should have known that from before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex literal like `/^\/|\/$/g` can be used to replace with empty string, or you may use `/^\/([^]*)\//` (match `/`, then any 0+ chars up to the last `/` capturing what is in-between the slashes) to replace with `$1`:

```js
var s = "/cat-dog-fish/";
console.log(s.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, ''));
console.log(s.replace(/^\/([^]*)\/$/, '$1'));
```

Note:

- `^\/` - matches the start of string and a `/` right there
- `|` - means *OR*
- `\/$` - matches a `/` at the end of string
- `([^]*)` - is a capturing group `(...)` that captures 0 or more (`*`) *any* characters as `[^]` means *not nothing*.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a="/cat-dog-fish/";

var d = a.replace(new RegExp("(^\/|\/$)",'g'),'');

console.log(d);
```

```js
    a.pathname.replace(new RegExp("(^\/|\/$)",'g'),'');
```